# Difference between AngularJS UI Router params object specified in state and views

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, parameters

I have just started working on AngularJS and specifically Angular UI Router project. While working on a project I observed that some of team members have specified `params` option object in `view` option object of `state`. when this is the case it doesn't accept optional parameters when passed through ui-sref/state.go.
     However I moved this `params` option object to state instead of view and optional parameters feature started working. I am using AngularJS 1.3.x and AngularJS UI Router version 0.2.13. Here is the sample code to explain more clearly what I want to say :

```
   $stateProvider.state('contacts', {
     url:"/user/{userId}/contact"
     views: {
        'view1': { 
            ....//other options
            params :{userId:0,contactId:null}
         }
     }
     ...//other options including `controller` and `resolve` options.          
   });
```

In above sample code(I have given minimal required information) params object is specified on `view1` object instead of on `contacts` state. Also `contactId` is the optional non-URL parameter which is passed on one of the use case and not passed in another one. However when I check `$stateParams` object in the controller specified on state it just shows up `userId` and not `contactId` even if I pass it.
   I fixed this issue when I moved `params` option object from `view1` object to `contacts` state object as shown below:

```
    $stateProvider.state('contacts', {
     url:"/user/{userId}/contact"
     views: {
        'view1': { 
            ....//other options
            //i have removed the `params` object from here..
         }
     }
     ...//other options including `controller` and `resolve` options.          
     params :{userId:0,contactId:null} //and have put it here.
   });
```

Now I have following questions :
 1) What difference does it make by changing where I specify `params` object. What are the significance if any?
 2)Is specifying `params` object on view altogether wrong configuration? If yes then why UI router doesn't complain and works with parameters specified in URL?
  If no then why it doesn't work with optional non-URL parameters?
 3) Any specific use cases one would prefer specifying `params` option object on `view` object than on `state` object?

Also another side effect I found when I moved this `params` option object to `state` from `view` object is I am no longer able to bookmark this url or even refresh url in browser. When I do this it redirects me to our home page. Maybe this could be how we are handling this redirection in our project. But just curious to have any pointers why this could be happening?(including how generally this redirection is handled using ui-router) Of course I am going dig deep into our project code to see why this side-effect is happening.
However I would at least like to have answers to my 3 questions(and subquestions) I have asked here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neither [the guide](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Multiple-Named-Views) nor [the API documentation](http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/site/#/api/ui.router.state.$stateProvider) say that a named view can have parameters. So I think adding `params` in the view was just a mistake, and it had no effect whatsoever.

So,

> 1) What difference does it make by changing where I specify params object. What are the significance if any?

In the views, ui-router doesn't care about it. In the state, it does what is documented in [the API documentation](http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/site/#/api/ui.router.state.$stateProvider).

> 2) Is specifying params object on view altogether wrong configuration? If yes then why UI router doesn't complain and works with parameters specified in URL? If no then why it doesn't work with optional non-URL parameters?

Yes, it seems to be wrong configuration.

> 3) Any specific use cases one would prefer specifying params option object on view object than on state object?

No

Comment: "In the views, ui-router doesn't care about it" --> But it works if I specify the "params" object on views at least for url path paramters. Is it by accedent then?

Comment: Also any pointers on the side effect I mentioned ? like how its generally done? Or at least what is the way to debug and find how its redirecting and any error if it is throwing while it redirects it

Comment: No, it's not by accident. Read the API documentation. You don't need to specify parameters. Having them in the URL is sufficient. The params is useful to make them optional and give them a default value.

Comment: ok thanks. So If I dont want to make the parameter optional its not even necessary to specify it in params object correct? I should just specify it in URL and when I pass it in ui-sref /state.go,it will map that parameter.